# Change buttons based on text jquery php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Is it possible to change buttons based on the text in a td cell with jquery? I don't want to have two different buttons in a cell. Here's what it looks like right now in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ocgpqug6/1/). (Sorry about the lack of jquery, I don't know how to approach it)

I have three stages in my mysql table. The column `process` goes from `waiting` to `processing` to `shipped`.

When it is `process` and `waiting`, **btn_cancel** is displayed.

```
<input type="submi" class="btn btn-danger" id="btn_cancel" name="cancel" value="Cancel Order">
```

When it is `shipped`, **btn_hidden** is displayed.

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="btn_hidden" name="hidden" value="Hide">
```

How could I achieve this? Or if this is not possible what's the alternative?

Comment: is the value of the cell going to update dynamically? if not, why not give the button the correct value when the page is built in php? if it is dynamically, then whenever it is set, also change the button

Comment: look at conditional statement in php http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp. Make condition base on your status

Comment: @pala_ it is displayed in the table and an admin would change it so I would like it to change on the user side but not sure how to acheive this

Comment: well they'd have to refresh the page, in which case your server side scripts can generate the correct button

Comment: I have server side I just need to change the buttons. The data gets displayed on the page automatically with ajax @pala_

Comment: I just improved the format for better reading. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more information on formatting

Answer (score 1):

The comments on your question may be correct but you asked how to do it in jQuery so here it is.

you can loop over each proccess table data and check the .text() and if the text === waiting then do what ever to the button. Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jamesharrington/7b7ddkcr/4/) based off yours.

```
$(function(){

  $('[data-proccess]').each(function(ind, process){
    var content = $(process).text().toLocaleLowerCase();
    if(content !== 'waiting'){
      $(process).closest('tr').find('[name="cancel"]').hide();
    }  
  });

});
```

With that said. You might want to look in to doing it on the server side if you are generating the page with php or something

Comment: I have tried your solution and it works. However, it doesn't run the actions when I implement this. For instance, without the code, when I click the buttons to cancel and hide. They work but when I implement this and I clikc on the buttons, nothing happens.

Comment: what action are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following. Please use appropriate value for #btn_id

```
$("table tr").each(function(i){
  var $tds = $(this).find("td");
  var status = $tds.eq(1).text().toLocaleLowerCase();

  if(status === 'waiting' || status === 'processing'){
    $tds.eq(2).find("#btn_id").attr('value', 'Cancel Order');
  }
  else if(status === 'shipped'){
    $tds.eq(2).find("#btn_id").attr('value', 'Hide');
  }
  else{
    $tds.eq(2).find("#btn_id").attr('value', 'Wait..');
  }
});
```

Comment: I have tried your solution and it works. However, it doesn't run the actions when I implement this. For instance, without the code, when I click the buttons to cancel and hide. They work but when I implement this and I clikc on the buttons, nothing happens.